# I am getting an error code ',' expected ts(1005) in node.js

Tags: node.js

I am getting the error ','expected ts(1005) from the line `valueInputOption: 'USER_ENTERED',`

I installed typescript using `npm install -g typescript` and have version right 4.7.3 right now. This didn't change anything.

Can someone help me fix this problem?

EDIT: Here is the section of the code.

````
    const gsapi = google.sheets({version:'v4', auth: cl })

    const opt = {
        spreadsheetId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 
        range: 'Data!A2:B5'
    };

    let data = await gsapi.spreadsheets.values.get(opt);
    let dataArray = data.data.values;
    let newDataArray = dataArray.map(function(r){
        r.push(r[0] + '-' + r[1]);
        return r;
    });

    const updateOptions = {
        spreadsheetId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 
        range: 'Data!E2'
        valueInputOption: 'USER_ENTERED'
        resource: {values: newDataArray} 
    };```
````

Comment: Just show us some code, we can't help you without seeing a single line of code.

Comment: When you i initialize an object with properties you have to separate them with a comma, like the error says. `let x = { a:3, b: 5, c: 12}`

Answer (score 1):

It's just a simple thing :

```
 const updateOptions = {
        spreadsheetId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 
        range: 'Data!E2', //<-- you forgot to add , here
        valueInputOption: 'USER_ENTERED', //<-- and also here
        resource: {values: newDataArray} 
    };
```

However you could have verified that by your self or if you are not familiar with typescript syntax or any thing else  try this https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-from-scratch.html
or any other tutos in internet